# Python turtle: if statement with position sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, global, turtle-graphics

I'm making an adventure/board game where the player can collect an item if he steps on it. So I made the function `check_item()` to check this:

```
def check_is_inside_screen(check_x, check_y):
    if check_x < -450 or check_x > 450 or check_y < -350 or check_y > 300:
        return False
    return True

def check_item(player_x, player_y):

    global pick_armor, pick_key, pick_sword

    if not pick_armor and -395 < player_x < -405 and 270 < player_y < 280:
        armor.hideturtle()
        pick_armor = True
    elif not pick_sword and 395 < player_x < 405 and 270 < player_y < 280:
        sword.hideturtle()
        pick_sword = True
    elif not pick_key and 395 < player_x < 405 and -320 < player_y < -330:
        key.goto(400, 325)
        pick_key = True

def move(move_x, move_y):
    player.forward(-100)
    px, py = player.pos()
    if not check_is_inside_screen(px, py):
        player.forward(100)
        return
    check_item(px, py)

def movePlayer():
    player.onclick(move, 1)
```

The thing is, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I play test the game and sometimes the `armor` turtle is successfully hidden, sometimes it just isn't. Also the `sword` object usually isn't hidden and the `key` just doesn't work. I tried getting rid of the boolean parameters, but nothing works. It could be also useful to know that the function is called inside of the `move()` function, which is called from the `onclick()` event. Basically, whenever I click on the player object, it moves and after that it checks the position.

Comment: please no code as images.

Comment: also don't compare booleans == True or == False, and avoid global variables. are the coordinates integer or float type?

Comment: I'm very sorry about the image, I'm new to the site and I read the indication for it only after the post. As for the booleans, I wanted a variable that stored the information that the player picked up the item, so that the if statement won't be considered afterwards. I get the player coordinates from the pos() method and when I print them out they seem to be integers.

Comment: try to create a [mcve] and post code as text. Do that and I may reopen the question

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

First, turtles crawl a *floating point* plane so tests like this will sometimes work, and sometimes fail:

```
x == -400 and y == 275
```

as `x` could come back as `-400.0001`.  You could coerce the points to integers:

```
int(x) == -400 and int(y) == 245
```

or test if the positions fall within a range of values.

Second, this code in your `move()` function is suspect:

```
    player.forward(100)
    return
    tx, ty = player.pos()
    check_item(tx, ty)
```

There shouldn't be code after a `return` at the same indentation level -- it will never be executed.  I would have expected your code to be more like:

```
def check_item(x, y):

    global pick_armor, pick_key, pick_sword

    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)

    if not pick_armor and x == -400 and y == 275:
        armor.hideturtle()
        pick_armor = True
    elif not pick_sword and x == 400 and y == 275:
        sword.hideturtle()
        pick_sword = True
    elif not pick_key and x == 400 and y == -325:
        key.goto(400, 300)
        pick_key = True

def move(x, y):

    player.forward(-100)

    tx, ty = player.pos()

    if not -450 <= tx <= 450 or not -375 <= ty <= 325:
        player.backward(-100)
        return

    check_item(tx, ty)

def movePlayer():

    player.onclick(move, 1)
```

I couldn't test the above without more of your code to work with but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but there are still some problems. As it turns out, the approximation of the pos() function is so bad that I had to check a range of values. But it still doesn't work. I'm gonna edit the question so that you can see the updated code. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: @Teolul, in your updated code, this is an error:  `-320 < player_y < -330`  Think about the nature of negative numbers and reverse the values.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. Now everything works perfectly. Thanks again for your help, I'll try to be more observant next time!